# Should I contact the university? I will be in the area?

Tags: united-states, faculty-application

I am wondering if It is appropriate to contact the university and let them know that I will be in the area if by chance I am under consideration.  We are moving back to our home state and my husband will be taking a tuck load there.  I can join him or not.  They stated that they would begin looking at applications on June 16th.  Thanks.

Comment: I suppose it's in the US ?

Comment: I take, you have applied to a position at said university? I would not propose that you contact them. They are making a decision on the applications, not bechause you are in the vicinity. It could sound a bit to clingy for them and result in a rejection.

Comment: you should maybe wait to see if you're invited to an interview (phone or so) and then say that you might be not so far from it.

Comment: @HATEthePLOT Can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can vote it up?

Answer (score 1):

I take, you have applied to a position at said university? I would not propose that you contact them. They are making a decision on the applications, not bechause you are in the vicinity. It could sound a bit to clingy for them and result in a rejection.

Comment: While for large R1 type universities this is correct, smaller less desirable schools often make choices based on availability and if applicants seem "clingy".

Answer (score 0):

If there is anyone in the department you applied to that you know personally or have sufficient shared research interests with that you think they might be inclined to support your application, I don't think that it would be inappropriate for you to contact them and let them know that you have applied for the faculty position and you would be nearby and available to drop by for a visit one day if they would like you to. I see this as highly unlikely to have a negative effect on your chances, and somewhat more likely (though still not especially likely) that something good could actually come of it.

Note that this recommendation pertains to contacting someone you know, or at least have some small affiliation with through shared research interests, shared acquaintances, coauthors etc. By contrast, sending a generic "look at me" email in connection with a faculty position application to a department chair you have no such connection to is in my opinion inappropriate, annoying, and may very well be counterproductive. Good luck!